# How to convert a Keynote file and preserve resolution of the images?

Tags: images, resolution, microsoft-powerpoint, presentation, keynote

I have a situation where we start with Keynote files, must convert them to Powerpoint and then back into Keynote before I can work with them.

The extra Powerpoint step is 100% necessary. The files need to be translated and the translation software doesn't accommodate Keynote.

The thing is when files are brought back into Keynote the resolution of the images are reduced. Is there any way to keep the quality of images intact while converting back and forth?

Comment: What version of PowerPoint will you use and with translation do you mean translate to another language?

Comment: Powerpoint 2010. [14.4760.1000 (32 bit) specifically.] Yes, translate to different languages.

Comment: You'll want to find out where the resolution loss occurs. Does Keynote save as PPT or as PPTX? If the latter, it's a zip file; you can open it, look in the media folder and there you'll find the images themselves. Extract a few and see if they're already downsampled.

Comment: Probably should be mentioned that macs (OS 12+) now have a built in translation service. This wouldn't necessarily replace a professional translation service but, for supported languages, it might help reduce some manual entry in Keynote.

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge:

why not generate a text file with all the textual content, run the translation system on that, and then incorporate the translated text into your Keynote, skipping the entire PP-KY-PP mess completely?

Comment: That would work but unfortunately Keynote doesn't seem to have a text export/import option. That would be nice though.

Comment: Hmm. Although I don't recall a discrete text import tool or function, I've copy-pasted text into Keynote more times than I can easily count - the downside is that's one text chunk at a time -  but then again, that would be true of importing text as well.

Comment: If Keynote does a decent job of exporting to PPT, you could do that first, then use a PPT macro to export the text to a text file. I've got some sample code here: https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00274_Export_Text_to_a_text_file-_extract_text_from_PowerPoint_-Mac_or_PC-.htm

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to save (File > Save As) the PowerPoint slides as image files.

This Microsoft Docs [page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/powerpoint/change-export-slide-resolution) explains how to edit the Registry to set a higher resolution for the slides. Remember to save a copy of the Registry before editing it.

When you will have saved the slides as images, you can choose whether to use them as slides or to crop the pictures with the help of a graphic editor and then insert them into the slides.

Comment: Hmm. Seems like an interesting workaround. It may not be feasible for my purposes in the long run but it's worth looking at.